# Add control programmatically to form in Java

Tags: java, forms, swing, netbeans, controls

I am trying to add a simple control to the form via code. I've

```
public main(java.awt.Frame parent, boolean modal) {
    super(parent, modal);
    initComponents();
    this.setLayout(new java.awt.BorderLayout());

    JPanel pnl = new JPanel();
    pnl.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    pnl.setBackground(Color.red);
    pnl.setSize(500, 500);
    add(pnl, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    pnl.setVisible(true);
}
```

When I run the application then I don't see the panel that I created. Can someone please tel me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention the layout that the current container is using, but likely it is GroupLayout, a layout associated with the NetBeans GUI builder, which does not respect BorderLayout constraints/constants. You need to re-think the layout of your entire GUI, especially if you're going to mix IDE GUI builder layouts with manual-coded layouts. This mixture can be done but it requires care -- create your GUI builder JPanels, create your own hand-constructed JPanels, and then combine them in a master JPanel(s) that use appropriate layouts. the specifics will all depend on what it is you're trying to create, something we don't know at the moment.

Perhaps this confuses you:

```
JPanel pnl = new JPanel();
pnl.setLayout(new BorderLayout()); // (A)
// ....
add(pnl, BorderLayout.CENTER);  // (B)
```

Line (A) sets the layout for pnl to BorderLayout
Line (B) adds the pnl to the BorderLayout.CENTER position of the ***current*** *container*, again one that probably doesn't use BorderLayout (a guess since you never show or tell us).

Also, do you call `pack()` after adding all components to the top level window and before displaying it? You should.

Also note that this is simply not needed since a JPanel is visible by default:

```
pnl.setVisible(true);
```